# AutoFixture fails to CreateAnonymous MVC Controller

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, autofixture, automoq

The code:

```
IFixture fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
fixture.Customize<ViewDataDictionary>(c => c.Without(x => x.ModelMetadata));
var target = fixture.CreateAnonymous<MyController>();
```

the Exception:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NotImplementedException:
>   The method or operation is not implemented.

`MyController()` takes 3 parameters.

I've tried the fix described in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514102) but it wouldn't work.

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET MVC are you using? How does the `MyController` constructor look? Does `MyController` have any writable properties? Does the exception provide more details (e.g. a stack trace)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[As it seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869968/how-do-i-apply-autofixture-customizations-to-anything-inheriting-from-a-base-cla#comment19120515_13875306), when using MVC 4 you have to customize the `Fixture` instance in a different way.

The test should pass if you **replace**:

```
fixture.Customize<ViewDataDictionary>(c => c
    .Without(x => x.ModelMetadata));
```

**with**:

```
fixture.Customize<ControllerContext>(c => c
    .Without(x => x.DisplayMode));
```

---

Optionally, you can create a [composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) of the required customizations:

```
internal class WebModelCustomization : CompositeCustomization
{
    internal WebModelCustomization()
        : base(
            new MvcCustomization(),
            new AutoMoqCustomization())
    {
    }

    private class MvcCustomization : ICustomization
    {
        public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
        {
            fixture.Customize<ControllerContext>(c => c
                .Without(x => x.DisplayMode));
        }
    }
}
```

Then, the original test could be rewritten as:

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture()
        .Customize(new WebModelCustomization());

    var sut = fixture.CreateAnonymous<MyController>();

    Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IController>(sut);
}
```

Comment: Note to others: I had to add a reference to `System.Web.WebPages` to get this to compile

Comment: FYI this is also required for `MVC 5.1.2`.

Comment: One issue is that whatever I do, the "c.Without" section throws a compile error.