# creating controller in a test using AutoNSubstituteData xUnit and AutoFixture

Tags: xunit.net, autofixture, nsubstitute, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am not convinced about the pattern, but I am trying to create a test like this:
I want to create the Controller, but have the *dependencies available as Frozen parameters* to the test.

The test is as follows.

```
    [Theory, AutoNSubstituteData]
    public void TestService(
           [Frozen] ITestService service, 
           TestController controller, 
           string value)
    {
        controller.Test(value);
        service.Received().ProcessValue(Arg.Any<string>());
    }
```

**I get this error as the test starts.**

```
    System.InvalidOperationExceptionAn exception was thrown 
    while getting data for theory WebTest.Tests.Controllers.TestControllerRouteTests
    .TestService:
    System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 
    Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NotImplementedException:     The method or operation is not implemented.
       at System.Web.HttpContextBase.get_Items()
       at System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider.SetDisplayMode(HttpContextBase context, IDisplayMode displayMode)
```

I have created the AutoNSubstituteData attribute from this [AutoNSubsituteData](http://nikosbaxevanis.com/blog/2012/07/31/autofixture-xunit-dot-net-and-auto-mocking/) post.
I have attempted to create a fake context to solve the problem.

```
/// <summary>
/// The auto n substitute data attribute.
/// </summary>
internal class AutoNSubstituteDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises a new instance of the <see cref="AutoNSubstituteDataAttribute"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    internal AutoNSubstituteDataAttribute()
        : base(new Fixture()
        .Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization())
        .Customize(new HttpContextBaseCustomization()))
    {
    }
}

internal class HttpContextBaseCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<ViewContext>(_ => _.OmitAutoProperties());
        fixture.Customize<HttpContextBase>(_ => _.FromFactory(() => Substitute.For<HttpContextBase>()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14985930/126014

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3514102/126014

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13869968/126014

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is really that [HttpContextBase.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.items.aspx) is **evil**, because it's a *virtual* property that *always* throws a `NotImplementedException`.

Usually, mock libraries tend *not* to override virtual members by default, and I suspect that this is also the case for NSubstitute. If this is correct, one option would be to configure the Test Double to override the `Items` property.

Another option is to ask AutoFixture to omit the `HttpContext` property from the Controller, if you don't need it in your test case.

Answer (score 1):

From  [one of the posts linked to by Mark Seemann](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985930/autofixture-fails-to-createanonymous-mvc-controller), we found the following snippet solve the issue for us-

```
fixture.Customize<ControllerContext>(c => c
            .Without(x => x.DisplayMode));
```